# DevC++ Linker Errors

Tags: c++, windows

I am receiving the following errors in my win32 api code in devc++:

```
[Linker error] undefined reference to `EnumProcessModules@16' 

[Linker error] undefined reference to `GetModuleFileNameExA@16'

ld returned 1 exit status
```

How can I solve this problem? I tried using

```
#pragma comment(lib, "psapi.lib")
```

since it was a linker issue but it did not help whatsoever.

Comment: Your linker is missing the reference to the library in which these functions are defined. What IDE are you using?

Comment: GCC doesn't support `#pragma comment`.

Comment: What version of Windows SDK you are using? WHat OS version?

Comment: You should probably get rid of Dev-C++, as it's usually the source of most errors.

Comment: Why would you use Dev-C++? Do you like torturing yourself? There are free up-to-date IDEs and compilers which *don't* suck. Why not use one of them?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Link with the library that provides the missing functions.

As mentioned in the question comments, g++ (which most likely is the compiler that you’re using with DevC++) does unfortunately not support `#pragma comment`.

Also, as mentioned in the question comments, DevC++ is a rather outdated and ungood IDE. Since you are using Windows, try out e.g. [Code::Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/) IDE for the g++ compiler, or Microsoft’s [Visual C++ Express](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/visual-cpp-express) IDE for Visual C++. And with the latter you can use the `#pragma`, if you want…

Comment: The right answer is to add `-lpsapi` to the linker options.

Comment: @ChibuezeOpata: no, that's not the "right" answer at all; it is of negative utility. you might benefit from exploring ["Give a man a fish"](http://bit.ly/19IxXJA). or perhaps not, i don't know.

Comment: Yes, [we can agree to disagree](http://orwelldevcpp.blogspot.com/) when you put any of your suggestions on a USB.

Comment: Your answer is not perfectly good. Kindly include the actual answer with your personal suggestion and I will revise my downvote. Nothing of what you mentioned in your answer solves the problem neither is DevCPP so bad or 'ungood'.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference I got it to work in CMake as follows, credit goes to Chibueze Opata:

`find_library (PSAPI Psapi)`

...

`add_executable(...)`

...

`target_link_libraries(Basic -lpsapi)`